# Do I have to include the C file that contains the definition for a function?

Tags: c, linker, include, declaration, extern

So I have been doing some reading and am I am still having trouble with extern keywords in C.

For instance:
I have a file called: *main.c* and within it I declare a function *int add(int a, int b);* (prior to its usage). However, the definition of the function resides within *math.c*. Does that mean that I must include the math.c and/or math.h file within the main.c (#include math.c/h) or main.h file in order to use the function without causing compile time errors? Or will the mere declaration of the function *int add(int a, int b)* suffice?

**In short: do I have to include the file that defines a function declaration?**

Furthermore, if the mere declaration of the function will suffice, is it good practice, or will the linker take care of it?

Thank you.

Comment: in general, never `#include` *.c files.  However, if you want to use a function that is in the libm library, then the easiest way is to use: `#include >math.h>` however, if you just want to make more work for your self, then write a prototype for the function into your `main.c` file

Comment: As the user3629249 said you don't include  *.c files. But you need to include your *.h file into your main file (I assume that you have a file with the math.h declarations) and you need to compile the math.c together with main.c i.e `gcc main.c math.c -o New_file`

Comment: Sorry, I think my question has been misinterpreted. It's not about the functionality itself, nor the math libraries involved. The file names were chosen to illustrate an scenario. The question I was really asking regarded the linker, and whether or not a file with a definition for a given declaration myst be included in the file that makes use of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include "math.h" in "main.c" and place the definition of `add` in "math.h": `int add(int a, int b);`

Then also include "math.h" in "math.c" and actually declare `add` in that file by creating the code that does the computation.

The compiler with then compile both .c files independently to .o files under Linux/MacOS, or to .obj files under Windows.  The linker then takes those two .o / .obj files and links them together to produce the complete executable.

As a general rule, header files that have a `.h` extension are intended to be included in multiple `.c` files, and provide information about what can be found in the corresponding `.c` file.  So `math.h` contains what's called a prototype for `add`, this allows `main.c` to know about the function, so it's able to use it properly, and `math.c` contains the actual code.

While not absolutely required, adhering to this convention will make your like much easier in the long term, especially when you have larger projects with many `.c` and `.h` files.  This is why you'll find it being used in just about all open source projects you download.

-- Edit --

Also, as a general rule, don't directly include external definitions in `.c` files.  Always try and place them in `.h` header files.  Placing them directly in `.c` files creates a maintenance nightmare if you have 100 or more `.c` files in your project, and you decide you need to change the prototype of a function.  Instead of editing a single `.h` `.c` pair, you now have to edit countless individual `.c` files.  This will be tremendously error prone.

Comment: I think I sort of understood the first two statements you made, however due to the use of the word "that" it's still a bit unclear as to whether or not you're referring to the former or latter file in the stated statements. I would like you to clarify the following [based on threads example scenario]. I declare the extern function int add(...) in main.c, but the definition resides in math.c. But I don't explicitly in code "join" (#include) in any way whatsoever the two files (not even via .h files). Will the declaration get matched with the definition of the file?

Comment: It should be clearer now: I've explicitly named "math.h" as the file that includes the definition of `add`.  That said, you are correct in not including "math.c" in "main.c".  As explained in Muzol's comment below your question, the compiler takes care of linking the two object files together.  In particular `main.o` will contain information that says "figure where `add` is, and use that here" at the place you call `add` in the C soure.  Likewise in `math.o` it places information that says "`add` is here".  ...

Comment: ... The linker takes those two pieces of information and makes it so that the call from `main.o` to `add` in `math.o` gets to the right place.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now. Thank you for your answer, dgnuff.